# Foundation 4 sass --watch issue

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, css-frameworks

Brand spanking new to foundation 4,

I've installed all dependancies, compass, sass, and zurb-foundation.
ran `compass create testproject -r zurb-foundation --using foundation --syntax sass`
... worked fine.

ran `sass --watch sass:css` in the testproject directory and I keep getting errors like so...
`error /Users/figmints/Sites/testssss/sass/app.sass (Line 5: File to import not found or unreadable: normalize.`
`Load paths:`
  `/Users/system/Sites/testproject`
  `/Users/system/Sites/testproject/sass)`

In the config.rb, the first line is `require 'zurb-foundation'`
Isn't this supposed to make the file `normalize.scss` visible to the project so that I do not have to copy each file located in my gems folder?

Could anyone direct me towards my mistake, please?

Thanks,
Seth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried compiling using `compass watch` in your testproject root directory, instead of compiling with Sass? Because you created your project with Compass, so you should use Compass to compile.

Comment: But Foundation doesn't depend on compass anymore, what if we want to get rid of compass? Compass is kind of a heavy dependency.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there's no `sass watch`. What you need to do is:

1. Navigate to your project's root folder (which is where your Compass project's `config.rb` should be) through your terminal
2. Type `compass watch` and hit Enter
3. See the magic happen (if you have nicely configured your `config.rb`, that is)

A Compass project should be watched by Compass. The watch function is why—IMO—Compass is so nice: it does something Sass naturally doesn't do.

Comment: There is a flag --watch which takes the sass directory and css directory as parameters. Any files saved in the sass directory will be converted to css and written to the css directory. Is this was compass watch does?

Comment: Sounds like it, but since I've never used it I'm not aware of the differences and simmilarities between the two.